# Loading PNG image to

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I'm looking for an efficient method to load PNG files as a TensorFlow 2.x date set. There are multiple answers here which all are using Tensorflow 1.x syntax. I also checked the [official Tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images) but they are using `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory` API which is only available in tf-nightly.

Is there any API for Tensorflow 2.x capable of loading images from a folder, assigning the subfolder as the label, and return a TensorFlow dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the *flow_from_directory* method. You might find this [useful](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_directory)